# Python: Use sets in conjunction with dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have this method here that generates a directed graph in the form of a dictionary where the values of a key are the nodes that the key points to, ie, {'stack': ['over','flow']}, stack points to over and flow...

```
def generateGraph(fileName):
    heroDict = {}
    graph = {}
    with open(fileName) as inFile:
        for line in inFile:#go through each line
            name_comic = line.rstrip().replace('"', '').split('\t') #split into list with name and comic book as strings
            if name_comic[1] in heroDict: #if the comic book is already in the dictionary
                heroDict[name_comic[1]] += [name_comic[0]] #add the hero into the comic's list of heroes
            else:
                heroDict.update({name_comic[1]: [name_comic[0]]}) # update dictionary with name and comic book
    for i in heroDict.values():
        for j in i:
            if graph.has_key(j):
                tempDict = copy.deepcopy(i)
                tempDict.remove(j)
                heroList = tempDict
                graph[j] += heroList
            else:
                tempDict = copy.deepcopy(i)
                tempDict.remove(j)
                heroList = tempDict
                graph[j] = heroList
        print graph #<========== the graph has duplicates, ie, values that are the same as their keys are present
    return graph
```

My question is, how can I implement the use of sets with dictionaries to prevent values that are the same as the key in question to be added to the key?

Comment: Why all the deepcopying?

Comment: And why not just test for `if j not in heroList` here?

Comment: the deepcopying is so I can remove a key while not removing the key from the main dictionary im using

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was thinking to use this but my graphs are huge, 100000+ keys so it isn't helping out in terms of efficiency. I was wondering if the same effect can be achieved with sets while not affecting efficiency much.

Comment: Without more detail on the `heroDict` contents I cannot say much about this, but it looks as if a simple `graph[j].extend(e for e in i if e != j)` would do; that creates a new list too.

Comment: Yes, sets can help there, membership testing is much more efficient with a set, but your code has bigger issues with all the copying, and the double loops.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your **graph[j].extend(e for e in i if e != j)** method is working very well in the case where **if graph.has_key(j):**, but in the **else:** it does not work because the key does not exist, how can I go around this so I dont have to use the deepcopy for the **else:** statement either?

Comment: See my answer below; without a defaultdict the `else` case would be `graph[j] = [e for e in i if e != j]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd recode your graph builder; using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [`collections.defaultdict` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) make the code *vastly* more readable:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def generateGraph(fileName):
    heroDict = defaultdict(list)

    with open(fileName, 'rb') as inFile:
        reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            name, comic = row[:2]
            heroDict[comic].append(name)

    graph = defaultdict(list)
    for names in heroDict.itervalues():
        for name in names:
            graph[name].extend(n for n in names if n != name)
    print graph
    return graph
```

There is no need to use sets here. Note that I used more meaningful variable names; try to avoid `i` and `j` unless they are integer indices.

Comment: I am getting key errors when I use this method. Any ideas why?

Comment: What are the key errors? Note that I forgot to set `graph = defaultdict(list)` until 1 minute ago.

Comment: It's happening at the line **graph[name].extend(n for n in names if n != name)** and it just says **KeyError:** then the name of the first key

Comment: That means `graph` is not a `defaultdict`. Add that `graph = defaultdict(list)` line and you are set.

Comment: Yup, it works like a charm, very efficient too. Thanks a lot for the help I really appreciate it.